# How to remove captcha image and it's textbox using css?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

Right now i am building extension for chrome which fills in the captcha for a site automatically, so there's no need for users to see that thing on the particular url.

WIth the url comes the custom css file for improving the UI Of the page, but i don't know how to hide that.

The website for which i am building extension is : https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tailored for that one page:

```
form[name="stud_login"] tr:nth-last-of-type(2),
form[name="stud_login"] tr:nth-last-of-type(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

It hides the two rows that contain the captcha data.